# Can't get CSS layout correct

Tags: css

This site: http://dev.calffl.org

Three bottom widget boxes labeled test, test 2, test 3.

Notice how the box extends down into the footer and overwrites the footer in a bad way?

That needs to go away, and the boxes should be 210px tall, with 90px of overlayed text/transparency anchored to the bottom.

I'm losing my mind apparently.

Comment: Does **"Can't get CSS layout correct"** have anything to do with **Wordpress**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.block` have a fixed height, whilst it's children elements have an even higher height, thus overflowing it's parent, and the wrapper too.

By removing the fixed pixel height on the `.block`, and setting a float on it's wrapper:

```
.homepageBottomBox-widget-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Then the site wrapper will follow suit, although I'm not 100% sure on what you need on the styling of the transparency part. But I've added a picture to see if that's what you're after.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Only real issue now is that there's a huge amount of padding at the bottom now.. Can we fix that?

Comment: That would be done by lowering the `#content` to less then the current `padding: 0 0 40px; ` May I ask, what browser do you use for CSS debugging?

Comment: Alright.. Fixed it.. I was just staring at it for way too long today, and nothing was making sense. Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Made an improvement on the transparency by:

1. Adding `position:relative` to your widget_sp_image class (or just widget class)
2. Setting `position:absolute;bottom:0px` to your widget_sp_image-description class.

Comment: Thanks! Worked nicely :)